# In predictive regressions, can we assume that the predictor follows the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Tags: predictive-models, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, stochastic-calculus

A predictive regression is a regression of the form
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
where $x_{t-1}$ is generally assumed to be a highly persistent stochastic variable, following an $AR(p)$ process of the form
\begin{equation}
x_t=\mu+\rho_1 x_{t-1}+\cdots+\rho_p x_{t-p}+\nu_t
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{E}(\nu_t\varepsilon_t)\neq 0$, due to the $x_t$ usually being highly persistent. I have seen many papers in which the predictor is assumed to follow an $AR(1)$ process and the asymptotic distribution of $x_t$ is assumed to follow local-to-unity asymptotics [see Campbell and Yogo (2006)], where $\rho$ is in the neighborhood of unity:
\begin{equation}
\rho=\exp(c/T)\approx1+c/T
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant and $T$ is the sample size. Due to this, the process $x_t$ is generally shown to follow the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (see proof here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-384-time-series-analysis-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT14_384F13_lec18.pdf ). I wonder if this can be extended to an $AR(p)$ process?  Is it too naive to impose the assumption that in the context of predictive regressions, the process $x_t$ follows this process? As in when the order of $AR(p)$ is unknown. Finally, does the OU extend to $AR(p)$ processes?

Comment: You need to make "extend" precise. In any case, no, it does not extend. The continuous time OU process is Markov. Therefore any time series obtained by sampling the OU process at discrete times must also be Markov. OTOH, AR(p) is not Markov, for p greater than 1.